# datatables, join same table?

Tags: laravel, datatable

Hellooo  i am using a datatable with laravel and I have the following doubt ...

```
$query = DB::table('categories')->select('id','name','parent_id')->orderBy('id');
```

I have this code that returns me all the categories ...

```
columns: [
        { data: 'id' },
        { data: 'image',
      render: function ( data, type, row ) {
        return data ? '<img src="/images/product/'+data+'" height="80" width="80">' : '<img src="/images/product/noproduct.jpg" height="80" width="80">'; 
 
      }
    },
        { data: 'name' }, // used for sorting so will hide this column
        { data: 'parent_id'}
      ],
```

And this other code that shows me a datatable with the categories but here the dilemma enters, how do I so that in parent_id instead of showing the ID ... it shows the name, should I join the same table? but in none that shows the name of the parent_id

EDIT:The same thing always happens to me, I post and find the solution at the moment, but now another question arose.

```
$query = DB::table('categories as c')->join('categories as k','c.parent_id','=','k.id')->select('c.id','c.name','k.name as namex')->orderBy('id');
```

This the correct way?

It have a fail... the categories without parent_id... not appear how can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a leftJoin so records without parent_id will be fetched too, otherwise, records will be restricted to have a parent

```
$query = DB::table('categories as c')
            ->leftJoin('categories as k','c.parent_id','=','k.id')
            ->select('c.id','c.name','k.name as namex')
            ->orderBy('id');
```